# Large Feature Values for Gradient Descent

Tags: regression, machine-learning, gradient-descent

Recently, I work on a linear regression model of my project. I have 200 samples, each of which has only one feature, to train my model.  When I try to apply `gradient descent algorithm` I cannot reach optimum parameter value even if I choose small step rate, which is equal to 0.001.

When I choose this step value, computed parameter values always cross the other side. I tried to plot how gradient descent algorithm behaves like.

```
    \        /
w1<- \*<---*/ -> w0
      \    /
       \__/
```

I thought the reason a little bit, and I concluded that main reason is the fact that feature values are very big. Feature values and ground truth labels are around 7000-8000.

Is there a solution to such a problem ? The feature values are from `cm^3` unit and ground truth labels are from `gram` unit. I think that I can convert them into `dm^3` and `kg`, but if I do that, I think that I may cause domain shift problem.

Comment: Is this the smallest learning rate you tried? Maybe try things like 1e-6 etc and see what happens..?

Comment: If it's really just a linear regression with 200 samples, there is a method for computing exact solutions by solving a system of linear equations.  There's rarely a need to use gradient descent in a situation like this.

Comment: I know using a basic linear system is a solution, but this is a general problem about gradient descent. Maybe using such a system can solve my problem, but the people who need to use gradient descent for large dataset and have big feature values need a solution to this problem. @MatthewDrury

Comment: @Goktug Fair enough!

Comment: Maybe the learning rate ist too small? Maybe you could use a different algorithm which modifiest the learning rate adaptively like ADAM?

Comment: It may be a good idea here to standardize your features.